# cannot resolve the symbol android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working with Google Cloud Messaging Service in android. But When I import `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService`,it shows `Cannot Resolve the symbol 'android'`. Kindly help me out. !!

Comment: Have you inlcuded the library project ?

Answer (score 0):

this comes with gcm library which is deprecated now.  check this  (https://github.com/google/iosched/issues/51)

Please use new google cloud messaging.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start